# Process extracted array of values into a formatted string value in JMeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, data-extraction

In JMeter, I have extracted multiple values in a page response to an arraylist using regex extractor (see **extracted value** below). I need to process the extracted values  into an variable in the format (see **required output** below) and substitute in the following request. How can this be achieved?

**Required Output:**
44772164,44772175,44772176,44772177

**Extracted Value**

```
Match count: 4
Match[1][0]=propertyKey="44772164">
Match[1][1]=44772164
Match[2][0]=propertyKey="44772175">
Match[2][1]=44772175
Match[3][0]=propertyKey="44772176">
Match[3][1]=44772176
Match[4][0]=propertyKey="44772177">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not an "arraylist", however our understanding of what "arraylist" is might be different
2. What you're showing doesn't look like [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to me

If you used 'propertyKey' as the "Name of created variable" and your [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configuration look like:

[image]

You can generate your "Required Output" using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the code like:

```
def requiredOutput = new StringBuilder()
1.upto(vars.get('propertyKey_matchNr') as int, {
    requiredOutput.append(vars.get('propertyKey_' + it))
    if (it  as int < vars.get('propertyKey_matchNr') as int) {
        requiredOutput.append(',')
    }
})

log.info('Required output: ' + requiredOutput as String)
```

Demo:

[image]
Also be aware that [using regular expressions for fetching data from HTML documents is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), you should rather use [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) for HTML and [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations) for XML.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Dmitri, thats worked brilliantly. Will update it to CSS selector extractor as suggested.